# Problem with Synchronization . App just freezes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized, notify

I am having a trouble with synchronized objects and I need your help . I am creating a game and I cannot get the synchronized threads to work .I am trying to create 2 threads which notify each other each time they change the textView .Can you help me ? Thank you in advance .This is my code :

```
   public void doPattern(int i) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock1) {
                    try {
                        lock1.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv.setText(text.get(0));
            synchronized (lock2) {
                lock2.notify();

            }
        }
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock2) {
                    try {
                        lock2.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
            try {
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            tv.setText(text.get(1));

            synchronized (lock1) {
                lock1.notify();

            }
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You wait on the two locks straight away. How can either thread do anything if they are both waiting?

Comment: I have tried to add lock1.notify() at the end but it doesnt work. This is just a test activity tho .I was trying to get better at notifies and synchronization so that I can use them in my app . Thank you tho for the answer

Comment: If anyone sees this I still have a question : Is there a way to notify each other like an infinite loop , and how can I start it . Cause I tried notifying at the end and nothing happens ...

Comment: You want to use `wait()` in conjuction with a conditional loop. E.g., make a `boolean` that is guarded by `lock1`. Use a loop to `wait()` while `boolean` is `false`. The entire loop should be within the `synchronized` block. When you want a thread to terminate, grab the lock, set the `boolean` to `true`, and call `notifyAll()` on the lock. Do the same thing for `lock2`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using two different lock use a single lock, here I have put a check (boolean flag) so that t1 will set the text first always. I have used condition while(1==1) to make wait() and notifiy() in infinite sequence, you can put your own condition to stop. I hope this will help.

```
volatile boolean flag=false;
public void doPattern(int i) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          synchronized (lock) 
          {

              flag =true;
              while(1==1)
               {   
                 try {
                      sleep(1000);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                     } 

                   tv.setText(text.get(0));
                   lock.notify();

                  try{ 
                    lock.wait();
                     }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
         }
    }});

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (lock) {
                 if(!flag)
                  {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                  }     
            while(1==1)
               {
                     try {
                        sleep(1000);
                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                     tv.setText(text.get(1));
                     lock.notify();
                     try {
                        lock.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                        }
           }
        }
    }});

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try {
        t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        t2.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```